# Passing Array as a function argument and setting elements values

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

So the solution to this problem I think is fairly simple but I must be missing something. All I want to do is pass an array to a function and then set the arrays elements values in the function to then use in the global scope.

```
int setArray(char* myArray) {
    char localArray[9] = "abcdefghi";

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
       myArray[i] = localArray[i];
       printf("myArray: %c\n", myArray[i]);
    }
    return(0);
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char* globalArray = NULL;

    setArray(globalArray);
    printf("globalArray: %s\n", globalArray);
    return(0);
};
```

The above code just crashes. at one point I had it working where I could set the globalArray in the function and print out its values but when I printed out the values in main() it was null.

I believe the issue lies with not setting up the pointer correctly and passing it, but I am not sure

any help would be greatly appreciated. thanks.

Comment: You cannot pass an array to a function in C.

Comment: `return` is a statement, not a function. Don't use parenthesis.

Comment: `localArray` only has 9 elements, but you copy 10, invoking undefined behaviour (remember that name, you will invoke it more often). And there are good reasons a pointer is not called "array" and vice-versa!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pointer `globalArray` doesn't point to a valid memory location. You need to allocate memory and store that address in `globalArray` using `malloc`, `calloc` etc.

You can allocate memory in `main()` or in `setArray()` function as dynamic memory allocation uses heap which is accessible to all the functions even after `setArray` has exited.

So correct code could be:

```
char* globalArray = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
if(!globalArray)
{
    printf("Memory could not be allocated!\n");
    exit(1);
}

setArray(globalArray);
...
```

---

Also You haven't copied `\0` byte to `myArray` in function `setArray()`

After the `for` loop you need `myArray[i] = '\0';`

---

Also you have `char localArray[9] = "abcdefghi";` in your code.

Here `localArray` is not a valid c string as it doesn't contain terminating `'\0'` character. Though it doesn't poise any problem for now but if you happen to print/alter `localArray` as string then it'll lead to invalid memory access (`SegFault`)

So to avoid that use

```
`char localArray[] = "abcdefghi";`
```

instead of

```
`char localArray[9] = "abcdefghi";`
```

Comment: Thanks @rootkea. I appreciate everyones input all the other stuff mentioned were silly mistakes on my end, but the concept that I did not understand that I am trying to implement (although not displayed above) is allocating the memory in the function will not work. I was confused why this was occurring because when I was printing the array while in the function, it was correct, but then once I printed it  when the function exited it was null. this is what was confusing me. I guess the bottom line is that there is no way to allocate memory in a function and then use that in main?

Comment: You can not access the local variables(static memory allocation) of a function one's the function gets exited as local variables (e.g. `int a`) use `stack` but you can access the dynamically allocated memory even after function gets exited as dynamic memory allocation uses `heap` which is globally accessible.

Answer (score 1):

It crashes because you don't allocate memory for `globalArray`.

Just add something like this:

```
globalArray = malloc(10);
```

before `setArray()` invocation.

Also, as it's already mentioned, your copy function is incorrect because you forgot about null-terminator when copying.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is one by definition.

Comment: @AndrewHenle yep, thanks, edited my answer. But don't you think that using `sizeof(char)` in this case makes code more descriptive? Or is it just an excess code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to either allocate memory for `globalArray` to point to, or you need to declare it as an array rather than a pointer:

```
char *globalArray = malloc( SOME_SIZE );
if ( globalArray )
{
  setArray( globalArray ); 
  ...
}
free( globalArray );
```

or

```
char globalArray[SOME_SIZE];
setArray( globalArray );
```

where `SOME_SIZE` is large enough to at least hold the contents of `localArray` in the `setArray` function plus a trailing string terminator (0-valued byte).

**Edit**

The reason your code is crashing is that you pass a `NULL` value for the `myArray` argument, which is an *invalid* pointer value.  Attempting to dereference an invalid pointer value (in this case, through using the `[]` subscript operator) leads to *undefined behavior*; in your case, it causes your code to crash.